# SMS to Database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I just built a notification system with codeigniter and a mysql database. Now I am wanting to make it so I can text a script and then have the information in the text saved to the database table.

The database is very simple.

It has a table name of `notifications` with two rows `school and body` School being the name of the school involved and the body being the actual notification.

The text message could be formatted like so :

```
schoolNameHere, BodyIsHere
```

Notice the `,` in the text body.

Is there a service out there for this or a simple solution?

Comment: What you're looking for is an SMS server. A simple google search should find you some services. It won't be free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twilio](http://www.twilio.com) is a cloud platform offering call and sms services internationally for all needs. They provide APIs for these services which is easy to customize for our own needs. They even have a one month free trial.